# "mv -i" in Python

Tags: python, bash, mv

I am currently converting a bash script to python and there is a command in bash : `mv -i`
I know `mv` means MOVE but I'm not sure how to use `mv -i` in Python. I tried `man move` as well but couldn't understand it well.

Comment: `-i` is `--interactive`, which prompts the user if a file would be overwritten by the move.

Comment: thanks @kwatford ! but suppose Iuse shutil.copy for a normal mv in Python.. for MV -i , do I have to use any other particular command ?

Comment: `man mv` might be slightly more appropriate than `man move`...

Comment: Also, `MV` and `mv` are not the same thing. `MV -i` isn't defined to do anything at all in POSIX, and won't do anything on the vast majority of systems. If you've installed some other program named `MV` on your PATH, it will do… whatever that other program does.

Comment: @twalberg: Unless you're trying to build a Midnight Commander-style full-screen console file manager, in which case you'll be calling `move(3X)` all over the place. :)

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you wouldn't want to "use `mv -i` in Python"; you'd want to use commands in `os` or `shutil` to do things natively.

But if you *do* want to use `mv -i`, you do it the same way as anything else:

```
subprocess.check_call(['mv', '-i', srcpath, dstpath])
```

Keep in mind that the whole point of `-i` is that it's interactive. Quoting from the BSD man page:

> Cause mv to write a prompt to standard error before moving a
>   file that would overwrite an existing file.  If the response
>   from the standard input begins with the character `y' or`
>   Y', the move is attempted.

So, you'd probably want to either let its stdin and stdout pass through, so the user can interact with it directly. Unless you want to, say, pop up a GUI alert instead of a console prompt, in which case you'll have to attach pipes and process things manually, which will not be fun.

---

If you just want to write native Python code that's "basically the same" as `mv -i`, that's not too hard:

```
if os.path.isfile(dstname):
    yesno = input("'{}' already exists. Replace? ".format(dstpath))
    if yesno.upper()[0] != 'Y':
        raise FileExistsError("'{}': already exists".format(dstpath))
shutil.move(srcpath, dstpath)
```

However, this isn't *exactly* the same. Most seriously, it has a race condition that the real command doesn't have (if you move a different file to `dstname` between the `isfile` call and the `move` call, it will get overwritten). But there are also all kinds of trivial differences, like the fact that it doesn't handle the case of moving multiple source files.

---

If you want to exactly reproduce the behavior of `mv -i` in native Python, it would go something like this:

```
fd = -1
try:
    try:
        fd = os.open(dstpath, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
            yesno = input("'{}' already exists. Replace? ".format(dstpath))
            if yesno.upper()[0] != 'Y': raise e
    os.rename(srcpath, dstpath)
finally:
    if fd > 0: os.close(fd)
```

Except that you also need code to handle the case where `dstpath` is a directory, so you're also going to want to add an `fstat` in there, and… Really, you'd want to read the source to [an open source implementation of `mv`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-202.2/mv/mv.c) in C, rather than guessing.

---

More importantly, why do you want to do an `mv -i` in the first place? If you look at what your program is actually doing, and what the user experience is supposed to be, there's a good chance this isn't the right answer.

For example, if you ask the user for a filename to save your data into, you *could* write your data to a tempfile and then `mv -i` it to the user's filename… but the user may prefer to verify the overwrite immediately, rather than having to wait until you've already generated the tempfile (especially if that takes a long time).